# custom binding does not fire?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying my first custom binding in knockout but cant seem to get it work. I got this sample from http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html.

script

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        debugger;
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        // Grab some more data from another binding property
        var duration = allBindings.get('slideDuration') || 400; // 400ms is default duration unless otherwise specified

        // Now manipulate the DOM element
        if (valueUnwrapped == true) $(element).slideDown(duration); // Make the element visible
        else $(element).slideUp(duration); // Make the element invisible
    }
};
```

html

```
<div data-bind="slideVisible: giftWrap, slideDuration:600">You have selected the option</div>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: giftWrap" />Gift wrap</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        giftWrap: ko.observable(true)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

jsfiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/dingen2010/2gpL6/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working here, http://jsfiddle.net/YkeeB/ (using the same code) - but it's also using Knockout v3.0 (which is what the examples in the documentation on the Knockout website are using)

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        // First get the latest data that we're bound to
        var value = valueAccessor();

        // Next, whether or not the supplied model property is observable, get its current value
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        // Grab some more data from another binding property
        var duration = allBindings.get('slideDuration') || 400; // 400ms is default duration unless otherwise specified

        // Now manipulate the DOM element
        if (valueUnwrapped == true) $(element).slideDown(duration); // Make the element visible
        else $(element).slideUp(duration); // Make the element invisible
    }
};


  var viewModel = {
        giftWrap: ko.observable(true)
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

For Knockout v2.3.0 and below, there is no method `ko.unwrap`. Instead, you have to use `ko.utils.unwrapObservable`. Here is a fiddle with it working for v2.2.1, http://jsfiddle.net/yt4Gs/1/ .

Also, just for future reference when using JSFiddle, don't put script in the HTML section - even if it is inside `<script>` tags. Put in the JavaScript section.